# Implement Growl in Java Application

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, implementation, growl

I want my Java application to make a growl notification. My IDEs are Eclipse and Netbeans, and I am trying to implement a library in either (so far it worked it neither). How can I just add the library to my project and then reference the classes from within my own classes? Moreover, where can I find an appropriate library?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Ok, now I have somehow managed to implement the library ^^ However: the following command fails:

```
System.loadLibrary("growl");
```

It returns following error:

> Message: no growl in java.library.path

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About an appropriate library you should just google it. I found this one (that is tested on 10.5 so maybe it will need some tweaks): http://www.cocoaforge.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17320

To add the library to your project in Eclipse copy it into the project folder (this is not necessary, you could just copy it wherever you want, also in extension folder of the JDK) and then add it through the project settings:

- open project properties by right clicking the project and choosing **Properties**
- go to **Java Build Path** option
- go to **Libraries** and add it

[image]

Comment: ok, I now have the library, but how do I access it from within my code? Neither can I import it nor can I reference the class name. It's not even listed among the suggestions/code completion.

Comment: you can specifically add source and javadoc (to help auto completion) by expanding the specific jar once you added to referenced libraries and setting the paths by hand..

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use AppleScript script engine in Java 6 on OS X to communicate with Growl. Here's a [blog post](http://blog.jayway.com/2011/04/12/send-growl-notifications-on-os-x-using-a-java-6-script-engine-and-applescript/) describing how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the network binding like in https://github.com/chamerling/JavaGrowl or https://github.com/aerofs/growljavabindings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.cocoaforge.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=17320) can help you.

If your classes are packaged in a JAR file, just like a 3rd party library, you should be able to put it in your project /lib directory and add it to the CLASSPATH using the IDE.  That should be all you have to do (if I understand your question correctly).